# Resolution for full screen WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, fullscreen

Following [the guide](http://josheinstein.com/blog/index.php/2010/02/fullscreenbehavior-wpf/) here, I have created a full-screen WPF application. But I met a problem: the various size & resolution of screens. For example, I want to put several sprites on the screen as buttons; but they are located at different positions in each screen, and even different to what shown in the XAML designer.

I have searched all over without a clue got. How can I fix this problem? (to make the buttons appears the exact place (in the center), and better, help the xaml designer reflect exactly what will happens when the program is running). Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I'm defining my page as a `Canvas` inside the `Window` element. Actually I like Canvas more, cause I can easily put my sprites anywhere, not like a grid.

Comment: How are you defining your layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should not use pixel values in WPF.

Instead, you should layout your content in `<Grid>`s with rows and columns, and it will automatically expand to fill the screen (based on the alignments and row / column definitions).

Comment: I'm defining my page as a <Canvas> inside the <Window> element. Actually I like Canvas more, cause I can easily put my sprites anywhere, not like a grid.

Comment: @HoàngLong and that is why you have problems scaling to different resolutions. "Canvas" type solutions can only scale when you know the aspect ratio won't change. This isn't true in the pc world.

Comment: @HoàngLong: Don't use canvas; it will give you a world of pain for scaling.  WPF's layout system is much more powerful, if you take out some time and understand how it works.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: my main problem is that when I margin a button, in running it doesn't like what the XAML designer draws. I guess this is the same for grid when scaling too.

Comment: @HoàngLong: Don't use margins to position objects.  Margins are meant to give padding around an edge.  Instead, use rows and columns, or StackPanels.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Maybe I should give it a try. I'll let you know as soon as I finish it.

Comment: If i have a question do i post here, or do i post it as an answer?
My qs follows, i am using a window in wpf in that window i have a grid, where all the magic happens.
But my screen size of the grid does not match the resolutions of different screens? how can thsi be ?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using the canvas. Also, do not rely too much on the designer to build your layout. Using Grids, Stackpanels and/or Dockpanels will give much better results (and scale when resizing your window). For example, if you use only the designer and drag-and-dropp all your elements, the designer often puts huge margins a bit randomly and this will not always scale properly if you resize your window.

Comment: in my case, I need to build an area that must look the same in the designer when the program is running. The fact that what the designer show is different to what the program shows (it's a bit right-oriented compared to the designer) annoys me, since I must make the interface exactly like the design.